# EMGU: remove regions in Black & White Images

Tags: c#, emgucv, contour

I am trying to remove regions in a black an white image that have number of pixels less  than a threshold.

I found online a solution over here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/263077/bwareaopen-Matlab-equivelent-in-EMGU

However in emgu version 3.0 I cannot use this solution because the **Emgu.CV.MemStorage()**  does not exist in EMGU 3.0, and also ***Contour_<_Point_>_*** does not exist either.

One solution is to run EMGU 2.4 however is it possible to run this code with EMGU 3.0??

In addition is there any other alternative method to remove white regions of pixel number less than a threshold?

Thank you!